# Making Microsoft Office Reminders get your attention

Tags: ms-office

Does anyone know how to have Office reminders pop up in front of any application? Now, if I'm working on something, they silently pop up in the background.

It's one of the few features I miss from Outlook on windows, and I keep missing appointments.

It's driving me nuts (not to mention generating hate from colleagues whose meetings I miss).

Or should I just junk Office reminders, and use another application?

Comment: Which version of MSFT Office for Mac are you using? Also what version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY want to keep using Office you could [sync office with reminders and iCal](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/10/the-ios-academy-how-to-sync-reminders-with-your-computer). But i'd recommend using iCal for this or if you're on office 2011 use the calendar in outlook instead of the reminder app.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Office Reminders on OSX, too.  The problem was that I was getting rid of the reminder box by hitting command-Q.  The reminders would go away for the remainder of the day.

Instead, I now clear the reminder by pressing Enter or Command-Enter, and then the reminder comes up for all invites.

As far as I know, the reminder window should pop up on top of all other windows.